# Null backreference when mapping to two instances of the same class

Tags: grails, orm, grails-orm

I'm currently working with Grails 1.3.7, and I have the following domain classes connected by a pair of one-to-one relationships:

```
class Parent {

    Child child1
    Child child2

    static constraints = {}
}
```

and

```
class Child {

    static belongsTo = [parent:Parent]

    static constraints = {}
}
```

In a separate service class, I have the following method:

```
def checkParent(child) {
    log.info(child.parent)
}
```

Lastly, in my controller, I have the following code:

```
    Parent parent = new Parent()
    parent.child1 = new Child()
    parent.child2 = new Child()
    parent.save(flush:true)
    childService.checkParent(parent.child1)
    childService.checkParent(parent.child2)
```

My log output shows me that one of the `Child` objects *always* has a null reference to `parent`, whereas the other has the backreference established as expected.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your Child class should be like this:

```
class Child {
    Parent parent

    static belongsTo = [Parent]
}
```

and then your code will work. the other thing is when you have two references to the same domain class for different domain class attributes you may want to check [mappedBy](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html).

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work either.  Based on the [Grails belongsTo documentation](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html), both of our `Child` definitions are valid (and identical) ways to define a bidirectional relationship; if one works, then so should the other (and neither one of them does).  Also, `mappedBy` would be useful if the relationship were more ambiguous, but because `Child` only has one reference to `Parent`, I don't think it makes sense in this case.

Comment: okay. there is something interesting. when i try it like `Parent parent = new Parent(child1:new Child(), child2:new Child()).save(flush:true)`, i can see that parent.child1/child2.parent is not null and has the correct value. however if i try it like the one in your controller action then i get `NULL not allowed for column "CHILD1_ID"` error. yes, we can change this from the constraints but why it is not throwing this error in the former way is a good question i think.

Comment: I revisited this issue with Grails 2.0.0 (the original problem I saw was with 1.3.7) and was able to recreate the unusual behavior you described.  From the looks of things, there's already been [an issue reported about this](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8337?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel#issue-tabs), and it appears that my original problem was solved between 1.3.7 and 2.0.  I'll mark your answer as the correct one and hopefully see a resolution to the newer problems soon.